# debian bookworm how to expand displayed apt reason for holding package

Tags: debian, apt, motd

Because of a kernelbug the debian people (can cause dataloss on ext4 filesystem) blocks kernel update (403 error forbidden)

[bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1057843)

I set kernel packages on hold so it is not blocking the upgrade from other packages.

But in a few days I'll have forgotten this (stroke broke something in head).

So my question is how can I expand this

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64
```

to something like this

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64 (kernelbug)
```

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: MOTD = "Message of the Day"; I don't think that's what you meant :) I'll just edit your question to say "Reason for holding the package", OK?

Comment: yes do if you wish. MOTD I  searching at the moment; if is also a good way. Saddly the debian wiki I found is a little bit outdate. @MarcusMüller

Comment: Made the change, nobody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`apt-listbugs`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt-listbugs/apt-listbugs.1.en.html). This tool will warn you if a package is buggy, then you can pin the package (it will not be upgraded). Once a fix is available, it will be unpinned automatically.

Description from manpages:

> if any such bug is found, apt-listbugs warns the user and asks how to proceed. Among other things, the user has the opportunity to continue, to abort the installation or upgrade, or to pin some packages (so that the unsafe installation or upgrade is deferred). However, pinning is not effective immediately, and requires restarting the APT session (by aborting and then re-running the same APT command).

> Each package pin is automatically removed by a daily cron job (or by an equivalent systemd timer), as soon as the corresponding bug is fixed in (or no longer affects) the package version available for installation or upgrade. When the pin is removed, the installation or upgrade of the package becomes possible again.

Comment: Does that mean I can unhold my kernelpackages? @GAD3R

Comment: @nobody You have the choice to install , hold the package (pin) and unhold your package.

Comment: Little update new kernel was offered after a fullbackup I installed it and my files are all there (ext4 filesystem in use) seemed to fixed.